# Apache Camel FTP - How to start the route manually

Tags: ftp, apache-camel

This Camel route should start reading files from a Ftp-Server:

```
from("sftp://user@...")
```

Now, I don't want this to start automatically, or polling, or similar. 
This should be started manually (externally, JMX).
I have other routes which are being triggered via a MBean, and I use for that the direct label:

```
from("direct:myRoute1")
```

Which is the best way to do the same and starting as the first action with an FTP-read functionality? Something like:

```
from("direct:myRoute2")
.from("sftp://user@...")
.autoStartup(false)
```

?
This is not working. After the manual-JMX-trigger no file is being ftp-read. I guess the two "from" starting the route work in parallel and therefore starting the "direct:myRoute2" does not trigger the FTP.

Kann I put the FTP-URI in another component, other than "from", to start the FTP-Read after the from("direct:myRoute2")?

BTW: This is an individual route, with no connection with other routes.

Thanks

Comment: 2+ from is deprecated, use only 1

Comment: Thanks Claus. Now, what should I use instead of the 2nd from?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

What you need is Poll Enrich:

```
from("direct:myRoute2")
.pollEnrich("ftp://localhost")
.to("mock:result");
```

Now trigger the direct (no matter what you send to it) and the ftp consumer starts.

Comment: Thanks Ramin. That's what I was looking for. Now I am having a 2nd question and I may open a new thread, or maybe you or Claus can answer here? **How can I limit the number of polling rounds?** I actually only want to run it once, but twice would also be OK. I just want the route to stop after it went through. Is there a way to configure that? In the URI or somewhere else?

Comment: I'm glad that helped you. There are a number of ways to achieve this. You can use Oncompletion for example. Read about it here: http://camel.apache.org/oncompletion.html
Apologies for answering here if you have already started a new thread. If you have, just share its link here and me and others will help you setting that up.

Answer (score 7):

Read the documentation about how to configure routes to not auto start:

- http://camel.apache.org/configuring-route-startup-ordering-and-autostartup.html

Then check out the control bus EIP which allows to start routes from other routes

- http://camel.apache.org/controlbus.html

And this FAQ talks about stopping a route, but starting would be similar

- http://camel.apache.org/how-can-i-stop-a-route-from-a-route.html

And there is also API on CamelContext to start route, or you can use JMX.

Comment: Hello Claus, thanks for your answer. Let's say I have an individual route. No connection with other routes. I built it this way: from("direct:myRoute2")
.from("sftp://user@...").autoStartup(false)                              Now if I try to trigger this route with a MBean this is still not running. Because autoStartup is still false? Do I have to change that? But the route is already initialised....

Comment: in the MBean using producerTemplate.asyncCallback  to "direct:myRoute2"

Comment: You need to start the route first, there is JMX operations for starting routes.

Comment: I start the route with JMX, that's not the problem. In the following route: `from("direct:myRoute2").from("sftp://user@...").autoStartup(false)` starting it manually (JMX) does not trigger an "FTP-read". Is that because I disabled the autoStartup, or because the FTP-URI is within a ".from(" ? If that's the case, which "method" could I use instead of ".from" for the FTP-read-process? ".inOnly"  ?